# ERROR [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)

Tags: python, websocket, ssl

Получаю ошибку [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007) при запуске вебсокета. В один день просто начала появляться, я ничего не менял.

```
def connect(self):
    print('LOG', 'Connecting to websocket')

    self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.url, on_close=on_close, on_error=on_error,
                                     on_open=self.on_open, on_message=self.on_message)
    self.ws.run_forever()
```

Папки C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL на компе почему-то нет.

Обычные requests.get работают без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло такое:

```
self.ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
                                    "check_hostname": False,
                                    "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                                    "ciphers": "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1"})
```